# How to properly handle back-pressure during `Transform#flush`

Tags: node.js, node-streams

What is the proper way to handle back-pressure from within a Transform's implementation of the `_flush` method? In other words, if `.push()` returns false while flushing, are there any mechanisms to properly handle back-pressure from downstream?

Documentation dictates to stop pushing as soon as `.push()` returns false, but then the Transform has no means to listen for when the downstream wants to resume reading, other than to override `this.read`; but what would that look like and are there any dangers to doing so?

Here is a working example you can play with.

```
const stream = require('stream');

// a string large enough to overflow the buffer
const S_OVERFLOW = '-'.repeat((new stream.Readable()).readableHighWaterMark+1);


class example extends stream.Transform {
    constructor() {
        super({
            writableObjectMode: true,
        });

        // some internal queue that will be emptied once writable side ends
        Object.assign(this, {
            internal_queue: [],
        });
    }

    _transform(g_chunk, s_encoding, fk_transform) {
        // store chunk in internal queue
        this.internal_queue.push(g_chunk);

        // done with transform (no writes)
        fk_transform();
    }

    _flush(fk_flush) {
        console.warn('starting to flush');

        // now that writable side has ended, flush internal queue
        this.resumeFlush(fk_flush);
    }

    resumeFlush(fk_flush) {
        let a_queue = this.internal_queue;

        // still data left in internal queue
        while(a_queue.length) {
            // remove an item from queue
            a_queue.pop();

            // intentionally overflow buffer
            if(!this.push(S_OVERFLOW)) {
                //
                // WHAT TO DO HERE?
                //

                // go asynchronous
                return;
            }
        }

        console.warn('finished flush');

        // callback
        fk_flush();
    }
}


// instantiate transform
let ds_transform = new example();

// pipe to stdout
ds_transform.pipe(process.stdout);

// write some data (needs to happen twice)
ds_transform.write({
    item: 0,
});

ds_transform.write({
    item: 1,
});

// end stream
ds_transform.end();
```

Piping stdout to `/dev/null` so that stderr still prints to console:

```
$ node transform.js > /dev/null
starting to flush
```

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is that you should be using a Duplex rather than a Transform. Since each call to `_transform` is actually buffering the data rather than applying some (a/)synchronous transformation to them, this type of implementation is better suited as a Duplex, whereby calls to `_write()` buffer data, and calls to `_read()` start pushing until backpressure is detected.

```
const stream = require('stream');

// a string large enough to overflow the buffer
const S_OVERFLOW = '-'.repeat((new stream.Readable()).readableHighWaterMark+1);


class example extends stream.Duplex {
    constructor() {
        super({
            writableObjectMode: true,
        });

        // some internal queue that will be emptied once writable side ends
        Object.assign(this, {
            internal_queue: [],
        });
    }

    _write(g_chunk, s_encoding, fk_write) {
        // store chunk in internal queue
        this.internal_queue.push(g_chunk);

        // done with transform (no writes)
        fk_write();
    }

    _read() {
        console.warn('called _read()');
        let a_queue = this.internal_queue;

        // still data left in internal queue
        while(a_queue.length) {
            // remove an item from queue
            a_queue.pop();

            // intentionally overflow buffer
            if(!this.push(S_OVERFLOW)) {
                // go asynchronous
                return;
            }
        }

        console.warn('finished reading');

        // nothing more to read
        this.push(null);
    }
}


// instantiate transform
let ds_transform = new example();

// pipe to stdout
ds_transform.pipe(process.stdout);

// write some data (needs to happen twice)
ds_transform.write({
    item: 0,
});

ds_transform.write({
    item: 1,
});

// end stream
ds_transform.end();
```

Then you'll get:

```
$ node duplex.js > /dev/null
called _read()
called _read()
called _read()
finished reading
```